# How do I resize the chat in Skype 8?

Tags: skype, user-interface

I can't seem to resize the chat portion in the call/chat UI mode of the new Skype 8 user interface. (See image for example)

- How do I make the chat section bigger?
- How do I navigate to a "full-screen chat" mode that I have seen before?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you can't. But there's a workaround.

1. Focus the call
2. Resize the entire window so it can't be any smaller
3. Hit the "chat bubble" button in the lower left corner
4. Resize window to how you want to have it again

And now the chat is full-screen.

If you switch to another contact in your contact's list? You have to repeat this workaround. Same with the "Go to Call" button in the top-right corner, so don't press it.

---

Another quicker workaround I stumbled across is "creating a new chat" through:

1. Pressing left alt to open the system menu
2. 'File' menu -> 'New Chat...' entry
3. Select the person with which you want to full-screen text

Even faster: You can skip step 1 and 2 by pressing the hot key for "New Chat" (CTRL+N)

My guess is that this last workaround just doesn't work for multi-party chats since I can't even see those in that "new chat" list, which only lists contacts and not chats.

Comment: A big plus for this answer and a big minus to the UI designers. This is one of the reasons I still use version 7.

Comment: You might not wanna do that because of security. I've heard older versions of Skype are exploitable. This happens when shady .DLLs are thrown in a temp folder somewhere by your browser and the the updater is automatically ran by Skype to nudge you to update.

Comment: V7 does not work anymore, so I was forced to update to 8.